# Difficulty with PRINT and IF statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my code is basically simulating the at bats of a baseball player (Joe DiMaggio) in each game. This is the code so far

```
import random
i = random.randint(1, 100)
j = random.randint(1, 100)
k = random.randint(1, 100)
l = random.randint(1, 100)
while True:
    if i <= 32:
        i = 1
    else:
        i = 0
    if k <= 32:
        k = 1
    else:
        k = 0
    if j <= 32:
        j = 1
    else:
        j = 0
    if l <= 32:
        l = 1
    else:
        l = 0
    m = i+j+k+l
    print("He went", m, "-4")
```

I'm wondering if it would work with all of the different IF and ELSE statements. As well, when I try to run this, it highlights the m in the print statement with the error: Invalid Syntax.

Any help on how to fix this?
Edit: The syntax error has been fixed, but now it only adds them up for the first time, the rest of the prints are all 4-4.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix your print statment:

```
print("He went", m, "-4")
```

or use string concatenation:

```
print("He went" + str(m) + "-4")
```

or string formatting:

```
print("He went {} -4".format(m))
```

Your code will then go into an infine loop recalculating the same value for `m` over and over again, as random values are *not* recalculated each time. `i`, `j`, `k` and `l` are *static*, they do not reference a function call they reference the return value of *one* call to `random.randint()` each.

You can simplify your code using a loop, which *does* recalculate `m` based on new random values each time:

```
m = sum(1 for i in range(4) if random.random() < 0.32)
```

Comment: That fixed the syntax, but theres a new problem!

Comment: So would the    m = sum(1 for i in range(4) if random.random() < 0.32 replace all the if and else statements?

Comment: Yes, it would, and the `random.randint()` calls too.

Comment: @user2557303: My sum does *exactly* what your code did; pick `1` 32% of the time, `0` 68% of the time, for each of four runs.

Comment: @user2557303: I use a float value in the range [0.0-1.0) (so 0 inclusive and 1.0 exclusive) instead of a integer value in the range [1-100], but the mathematics is the same. We are just cutting out a lot of unneeded extra code to turn the `random.random()` value into an integer range choice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the concatenation operator.

```
print("He went " + str(m) + "-4")
```

Thus you are concatenating the output as a single string before you print it